# How to remove unnecessary blue outlines of focused checkbox in Mozilla Firefox 89

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox

Focused checkbox in Firefox 89 looks like:

[image]

By using userContent.css file - `input[type="checkbox"] {outline: none;}` does not help. Are there any other ways? Perhaps at `about:config`?

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried removing the border style? Firefox might be weird to add that instead of an outline.

Comment: Unexpectedly - instead of property value `none` it has to be `0`... And it's working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus{
    outline:0;
 }
```