# How to remove the focus-visible styles around checkboxes/radio buttons in Firefox 89+ (Proton)?

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox, radio-button

Pretty much the same question as this:
[How to remove unnecessary blue outlines of focused checkbox in Mozilla Firefox 89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719013/how-to-remove-unnecessary-blue-outlines-of-focused-checkbox-in-mozilla-firefox-8)

**But:**
Navigating a form with a keyboard (using the `TAB` key) still shows the same styles around checkboxes/radio buttons.
These styles ought to be `:focus-visible` styles, but the following does not remove them:

```css
[type="checkbox"]:focus-visible,
[type="radio"]:focus-visible {
    outline: 0;
}
```

I also tried removing any `box-shadow`, `border` and all of that with `!important`.
No luck.

**Is there a CSS solution to remove these new Firefox styles around keyboard focused checkboxes/radio buttons?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed. In Firefox 92 the following CSS once again removes the focus-visible styles around checkboxes/radio buttons as expected:

```css
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```